# Bulk collecting a subset of columns from Oracle Cursor

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, cursor

A **stored procedure** is given that can't be changed. It returns **a cursor** with a number of columns in the result. Is there a simple way in Oracle to `BULK COLLECT INTO`only a subset of columns provided by the cursor?

`FOR` loops and new collection types should be avoided. I would not like to fetch all data from the cursor, just the data that is needed.

For example to `BULK COLLECTION INTO` all columns from the cursor the following would work:

```
FETCH s_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO staff_ids;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I see you added an extra restriction for no new collection types. What problem are you trying to solve? Is it to improve performance?

Comment: Yes, basically I would like to use all resources of the language to avoid performance leaks. I think I will have to copy a stored procedure and remove unneeded columns to avoid fetching more data than needed. Even though it will result in code duplication.

Comment: Yep, to avoid performance leaks you need a modified/new stored procedure. Disposing unwanted columns after opening a cursor means that the database has already done all the hard work, hence the performance leak has already happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no", you will have to do one of the things you have said you don't want to do unless you can get the stored procedure changed, or get a new stored procedure written that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dispose of unwanted columns immediately.

You could declare PL/SQL tables for each column of the cursor like this:

```
type c_col1 is table of s_cursor.col1%type index by pls_integer;
type c_col2 is table of s_cursor.col2%type index by pls_integer;
type c_col3 is table of s_cursor.col3%type index by pls_integer;
t_col1 c_col1;
t_col2 c_col2;
t_col3 c_col3;
```

and bulk collect into these tables:

```
fetch s_cursor bulk collect into t_col1, t_col2, t_col3;
```

and delete the collections you don't need:

```
t_col2.delete;
t_col3.delete;
```

However, this is more code to write and takes more time to execute than just bulk collecting all columns from the cursor and pretending that the unwanted columns aren't there.